# click on div element inside an <a> tag

Tags: javascript

I have a set of div elements inside `<a>` tag with it's href.

The question is that there is a div inside of it with its own click event and I want that in case the div element trigger the click event, the `<a>` tag should not be triggered.

The function that manage the div click event try to stop propagation with no success.

```
if (!e) var e = window.event;
e.cancelBubble = true;
if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
```

What's wrong?

Comment: jQuery at hand? Simply do `return false;` in the event handler.

Comment: Yes, I use jQuery. Tried the return false; sentence in the function that manage the div click event and still the <a> tag trigger.

Comment: Whenever someone asks about block elements inside inline elements, it makes me shiver. Guess I'm not quite all the way used to HTML5 yet.

Comment: @theHacker—that doesn't work for elements inside links. Even if event propagation is cancelled (per the OP), the link is still followed. The OP can use the W3C [*preventDefault*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow-default-cancel) method.

Comment: @RobG jQuery calls both `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`. It does not matter what element the handler is attached to. See http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js line 4668.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery to attach to the event, then do

```
e.preventDefault();
```

JQuery normalizes the event object so this method is available on all browsers (otherwise older IE's don't have it).

Here's the documentation for [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

If that doesn't help, then try attaching a `click` handler on the `<a>` itself and call `preventDefault()` from that.

Comment: *preventDefault* is part of the W3C event model, you don't need jQuery to call it, see [*Document Object Model (DOM) Level 3 Events Specification §3.2*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow-default-cancel). For IE, support was added in [*version 9*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975460(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @RobG - Yup, that's what I said. :)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is the same whether or not you're using jQuery (or most other libraries).

When a link contains another element whose click event shouldn't cause navigation, then simply call [*preventDefault*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow-default-cancel) on the event. There is no jQuery magic here, it's just using a default DOM method:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

An example:

```js
function foo(event) {

  console.log(event.target.textContent);

  if (event.stopPropagation) {
    // Stop propagation
    event.stopPropagation();
    // Stop default action
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  // IE model
  event.cancelBubble = true;
  event.returnValue = false;
  return false;
}

// Attach the listeners
document.getElementById('d0').addEventListener('click', foo, false);
document.getElementById('d1').addEventListener('click', foo, false);
```

```html
Click on the Div, no click reaches the A element
<a href="#" onclick="console.log('Click reached ' + this.textContent)">Link
  <div id="d0">Div</div>
</a>Click on the Div, the link isn't followed
<a href="http://www.apple.com">Apple
  <div id="d1">Div</div>
</a>
```

The trick is that a click on the `div` doesn't bubble to the link, but without *`preventDefault`*, link is followed anyway.

A better idea is to not to do this at all. The `div` doesn't appear to belong to the A element, so put it outside. Then there are no issues with a click on the `div` causing navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to multiple things then perform an action determined in the callback.

```
$('.obj1, .obj2, .obj3').on('click', function (event) {
  var target = $(event.target);
  if (target.hasClass('.obj1')) {
    # do stuff
  }
// ...
```